# JPA specification subquery search via REST

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem to search inside 2 class with many to many relation and
a join table. I would like to know how to fix my code and also the url 
request to do to start this search using spring boot 1.5.

1) I would like to get all professor with ( student.names = john and professor.namep = david )

student

```
private Long ids;
private Long names;
```

professor

```
private Long idp;
private Long namep;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(name = "StudentProfessor",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idp") },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ids") })
private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<>();
```

Actualy i can only search to get all professor with name corresponding using this :

SPECIFICATION

```
public class ProfessorSpecification implements Specification<Professor> {

private Professor filter;

    public ProfessorSpecification(Product filter) {
        super();
        this.filter = filter;

    }
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Professor> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq,
            CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
        if (filter.getType() != null) {
            p.getExpressions()
                    .add(cb.equal(root.get("names"), filter.getNamep()));
        }
    return p;
    }

}
```

RESTCONTROLER

```
@GetMapping(path = "/search/professor")
public ResponseEntity<List<Professor>> searchProfessor(Professor searchedProfessor) {
    Specification<Professor> spec = new ProfessorSpecification(searchedProfessor);
    List<Professor> result = repository.findAll(spec);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

But i don't know how to make subquery for this case

2) I would like to know the url to make a search for this

I tried this

```
@GetMapping(path = "/search/professor{p}/student{s}")
```

for http://localhost:8080/search/professor?namep=john/student?names=david
without success

Comment: Does `Professor` entity defines a many-to-many with `Student`? Can you edit your answer with entities classes code?

Comment: @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
   CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH,
            CascadeType.PERSIST})
 @JoinTable(name = "StudentProfessor",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ids") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idp") })
    private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<>();